# C++ pass function to call by template type by parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++98

I have a class `A` that is a wrapper around a container of template objects of type `T`. `T` is expected to be a class in this use case. `A` has no reference whatsoever on the provided `T` type.

Is there a way to implement a function in `A` to call a function of `T` passed by parameters? Pseudocode:

```
template <class T>
void A:callFunction(functionToCall, functionParams, ...) {
        objectT->functionToCall(functionParams, ...);
}
```

objectT is of type `T`, functionToCall is `void`

I have not been able to find if it's really impossible to do in C++98 and why. Any possible workaround would help too.

Comment: Not clear where `T` is used in the method.

Comment: What would the type of `functionToCall` be?

Comment: @Jarod42 objectT is of type `T`. `functionToCall` is `void`.

Comment: Read "Modern C++ Programming" by Andrei Alexandrescu, Chapter 5. It solves a similar scenario using template metaprogramming to create a "variadic" Command Pattern.

Comment: @KeillRandor Thanks, it looks like exactly what I need. I would definitely accept it as answer if you could demonstrate it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, for example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct bar
{
  void say(int a, int b)
  { cout << a << ' ' << b << endl; }
};

template <typename T>
struct foo
{
  template <typename fptr>
  void say(fptr f, int a, int b)
  {
    (i.*f)(a, b);
  }

  T i;
};

int main() {
  foo<bar> f;
  f.say(&bar::say, 10, 100);
}
```

(this will compile with -std=c++98 for example on gcc)

If you don't want to use a template parameter for the member function, something like;

```
void say(void (T::*f)(int, int), int a, int b)
{
  (i.*f)(a, b);
}
```

Ought to work too..

Comment: This is good enough for now. For a more complete solution I would look into using [TypeList template](http://loki-lib.cvs.sourceforge.net/loki-lib/loki/include/loki/Typelist.h?view=markup) and other template metaprogramming from loki.

Answer (score 1):

As @Nim said, it's possible, as long as you know at least the **number** of arguments to be forwarded (types can be "templated") and define a function only for that number of arguments (or multiple functions using overloading). There's no possibility to create a function forwarder for any number of arguments.

This is only possible in C++11 using the "variadic template" feature:

```
template <class T, class Function, class... Args>
void A::callFunction(Function functionToCall, Args... functionParams) {
    bind(objectT, functionToCall, functionParams...);
}
```

Note that this:

```
objectT->functionToCall(functionParams, ...);
```

is not possible at all because you cannot specify a symbol defined inside a class as a "free symbol". However you can try to exploit the "pointer to member" feature and do this:

```
(objectT->*functionToCall)(functionParams, ...);
```

as long as this "functionToCall" is a pointer to member function of the class to which's object *objectT* points. For example:

```
x->callFunction(&T::something, a, b);
```

Comment: "This is only possible in C++11 using the variadic template feature". That's not right, you can do it using template metaprogramming and typelists.

Comment: Tell me then, why the Boost library in the version for C++98 has created the boost::function's call operator in something about 50 overloads, each one for particular number of arguments.

What is really impossible is to provide one simple definition that will cover the calls for whatever number of arguments you'd like to forward. With a long and complicated definitions it's possible, of course - the question may be whether it's worth it.

Comment: What Boost did (and Loki, and other libraries), is using -as I said- template metaprogramming and typelists. And they did it because it's worth.

Comment: No kind of template metaprogramming in C++ would help you expand the lists of function arguments in "infinity" (virtually unlimited number). The best thing I can imagine is that there already is a facility that has the declaration for up to 50 function arguments prepared from upside. Another possibility is with preprocessor. In the early days I saw also in Boost a Perl script that was generating header parts for boost::function. This is, again, meaningless today - we have C++11 and variadic templates.